# Store information about a directory

Tags: php

Other than the foldername, is there a way to get/set information about a directory to the actual folder itself?

I want to set a directory priority so folders are displayed in a certain order by assigning a number to each.

Comment: What file system are you working with?  Any reason you can't preface the directory names with "001," etc.?

Comment: Why don't you do it with a Hash of your own? In parallel with the information you got (I assume) from the Operating System?

Comment: The folders are named so that they relate to the content of the webpage they display - for SEO purposes - the file system is unix, and I'm using PHP.

Comment: You did not accept an answer yet. Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer and why the given answers do not satisfy you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with Extended File Attributes:

- https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

> Extended file attributes is a file system feature that enables users to associate computer files with metadata not interpreted by the filesystem, whereas regular attributes have a purpose strictly defined by the filesystem (such as permissions or records of creation and modification times).

Try the xattr API to get/set them:

- http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.xattr.php

Example from Manual:

```
$file = 'my_favourite_song.wav';
xattr_set($file, 'Artist', 'Someone');
xattr_set($file, 'My ranking', 'Good');
xattr_set($file, 'Listen count', '34');

/* ... other code ... */

printf("You've played this song %d times", xattr_get($file, 'Listen count'));
```

Comment: @Jim You are welcome. Make sure to read http://docs.php.net/manual/en/xattr.setup.php to learn the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for NTFS for sure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29
Don't know if such a feature exist for *nix file systems.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to anchor your program logic in the filesystem of the OS? That isn't a proper way to store such a information. One reason is that you leave your application domain and **other programs could override your saved information**.

Or if you move your application to a newer server, you may run in trouble that you cant transfer this information (e.g. as the new environment has another filesystem).

It is also bad practice to suppose a specific filesystem where your application is running.

A better way is to store this in your application (e.g. database if you need it persistent).

A simple array can do this job, with key as priority and value an array with objects of [Directory](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php) for example.

It could look like this:

```
array(
    0 => array( // highest prio
        0 => DirObject,
        1 => DirObject,
        2 => DirObject
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => DirObject,
        1 => DirObject,
        ...
    ), ...
```

Then you can present your folders with an flatten function or a simple foreach. And can easily save it as serialized/jsoned string in a database.

Comment: The data is persistant, this is a small website and for the sake of this particluar task I wasn't keen on maintaining a folder structure then also having to store some of that info in a database table, rather just keep it to one data source - do you see my point?